# Is there a way to extract hours per month from a datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime column of elements which are something like `2010-05-31 00:00:00` and continue for various months. I want to find a way to extract the hours per month for each datetime object as I have another column I want to divide by the hours per month. Is there a way to do this cleanly?

The values are between a couple of months like this:

```
Time                 Value
2000-01-02 00:00:00  200
2000-01-03 00:00:00  300
...
```

I would want another column that is basically `Value/total` hours per month for Time so for january it would be `200/744, 300/744 (31 days=744 hours)` etc and this continues for feb, march etc.

Comment: do you just need the hours in the given month (e.g. January) or the hours that remain in the month of a given date?

Comment: @MrFuppes Hours of the total month so Jan,Feb, March etc as some sort of variable so I can do Value/variable

Comment: Extracting the hours per month is a lot easier using the built-in module called calendar: `from calendar import monthrange` `total_days = monthrange(2022, 1)[1]` `total_hours = total_days*24` `print(total_hours)` result: `744`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` comes with all you need; use [.days_in_month](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.days_in_month.html) and multiply by 24 to get hours, e.g.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df['hours_in_month'] = df['Time'].dt.days_in_month * 24

print(df)
        Time  Value  hours_in_month
0 2000-01-02    200             744
1 2000-01-03    300             744
2 2000-02-01    400             696
```